# Enumerate list numbering to include chapter number

Tags: lists, enumerate

How does one include chapter number in the enumerate list number? For example if I have list in chapter 3, I would like to have the following list (independent of section in which it occurs). 
The numbering should continue across different enumerate lists in the same chapter.

Example:

> **Chapter 3**
>   *Section 1*
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit:
>      3.1 Pellentesque
>      3.2 a aliquam
>      3.3 Elis
>   *Section 2*
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit:
>      3.4 Pellentesque
>      3.5 a aliquam
>      3.6 Elis
>   **Chapter 4**
>   *Section 1*
>   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit:
>      4.1 Pellentesque
>      4.2 a aliquam

Comment: what if you have two `enumerate` lists in chapter 3? Should both of them start with 3.1 ?

Comment: of yes, of course there should be continuation in list numbers across different enumerate lists in the same chapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `enumitem` and `etoolbox` package, the important parts are:

```
 % include the chapter number
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

 % restart the enumerate list every chapter
 \preto\chapter{%
   \restartlist{enumerate}%
}
```

Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
 \documentclass{report}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

 % include the chapter number
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

 % restart the enumerate list every chapter
 \preto\chapter{%
   \restartlist{enumerate}%
}

 \begin{document}

    \chapter{one}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{testref} first
        \item second and cross reference: \ref{testref}
    \end{enumerate}
    more
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item third
        \item fourth
    \end{enumerate}

    \chapter{two}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item \label{secondref} first
        \item second and cross reference: \ref{secondref}
    \end{enumerate}
    more
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item third
        \item fourth
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{document}
```