# How to globally resume enumerate counter but restart per chapter?

Tags: enumitem

I try to have enumerate resume its numbering but restart with each chapter. I have found a way to restart the counter here:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/348942

However, the solution does not resume the counter when certain environments are involved, like a proof.

Here is what I have so far (but it does not resume the counter after the proof):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% include the chapter number
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

% restart the enumerate list every chapter
\preto\chapter{%
  \restartlist{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{one}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
more
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item third
    \item fourth
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
more
\begin{enumerate}
  \item fifth
  \item sixth
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{two}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
more
\begin{enumerate}
  \item third
  \item fourth
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, do you want a separate "proof" enumerate counter or do you wish to reset the enumerate counter at the beginning of a proof environment?

Comment: @nox Oh, I see now that I have formulated it incorrectly. I want the counter just to resume with 1.5 after the proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `enumitem` saves the resuming data (counter etc.) locally, and `LaTeX` forgets about these saved data after the current group ends. You could patch the `\enit@setresumekeys` command and replace `\def` by `\gdef` in it. Since there are two `\def` entries, I had to use the `\patchcmd` twice (it is defined in `etoolbox` like `\preto`. The changed code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}

% include the chapter number
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\thechapter.\arabic{*},resume}

% restart the enumerate list every chapter
\preto\chapter{%
  \restartlist{enumerate}%
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\enit@setresumekeys}{\def}{\gdef}{}{}
\patchcmd{\enit@setresumekeys}{\def}{\gdef}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{one}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
more
\begin{proof}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item third
    \item fourth
  \end{enumerate}
\end{proof}
more
\begin{enumerate}
  \item fifth
  \item sixth
\end{enumerate}

\chapter{two}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{enumerate}
more
\begin{enumerate}
  \item third
  \item fourth
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And the first page:

[image]